# What does the EE stand for in EE bonds?

Tags: united-states, bonds, terminology, treasury

I wonder what the letters "EE" represent in "EE bonds", i.e. whether it's an acronym and if so, what the full form of the EE acronym? I searched quite a bit and couldn't find the answer. I know what EE bonds are, but don't know why the two letters "EE" are used to designate these bonds.

Comment: There were Series A, B, C, D and E bonds.  https://www.treasurydirect.gov/savings-bonds/historical-retired-bonds/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a trivia question that has nothing to do with personal finance and will not be of any use to anyone in the world except for the OP.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't stand for anything. Savings bonds were numbered alphabetically and the EE series replaced the former E series bonds.

> Series E bonds were introduced in 1941 as war bonds but continued to be a retail investment long after the end of World War II. Issued at a discount of the face value, the bonds could be redeemed for the full face value when the bond matured after a number of years that varied with the interest rate at the time of issuance. If not redeemed at maturity, the bonds would continue earning interest for a total of 40 years if issued before December 1965, or for 30 years if issued in December 1965 or later. **Series E was replaced by Series EE bonds in 1980, and the last issued Series E bonds ceased earning interest in 2010.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Savings_Bonds#Series_E